# Are there any battery backup options that work with a PoE powered Pi?

Tags: power, battery, alternative-power, hat, poe

Looking to have a Pi (4) that is powered over PoE - are there any battery backup options (i.e. hats) that can be stacked with the PoE hat & supply power if/when the PoE fails (and then re-charge the battery from PoE power)?

note: I am looking for solutions that allow for the ethernet cord that is supplying the PoE to be temporarily disconnected, not options for creating a battery-backed PoE injector

Comment: Your can extra IEEE 802.3bt 4PPoE 2018 specifies 50W 900mA, regulate it to 5V, say, and DIY your own HAT.

Comment: @tlfong01 mind posting details of what "DIY your own HAT" would involve, i.e. what are the necessary pin connections between the Pi and the standard POE hat?

Comment: Hi @user2813274, Well, let us start with the PoE HAT - Raspberry Pi PoE HAT - The Raspberry Pi PoE HAT powers a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ via an Ethernet cable. Power-sourcing equipment is required on the Ethernet network. https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/poe-hat/.

Comment: I googled the product doc but don't found updated info! :( Raspberry Pi PoE HAT product brief (Not dated, Rpi4 not mentioned)
https://static.raspberrypi.org/files/product-briefs/Raspberry-Pi-PoE_HAT-Product-Brief.pdf.

Comment: Our DIY PoE UPS needs to detect if the PoE 37/44+V is present.  So let us refresh our memory on the PoE thing: Power over Ethernet - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet

Comment: And we need to google more commercial HATs for reference, before prototyping our own: (1) WaveShare SW6106 Lipo Rpi HAT 
https://www.waveshare.com/li-ion-battery-hat.htm, (2) WS Lipo HAT: 
https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Li-ion_Battery_HAT.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways to do what you want.

1. Do away with the POE hat, and use a POE spliter that terminates in USB and supplies 5V on that port at "sufficient" current.  For a Pi4 you'll want USB-C and older Pi would need Micro USB.
   https://www.adafruit.com/product/3785 and https://www.adafruit.com/product/4552 would work perfectly.  Then feed the USB port into a USB power bank, to act as your UPS.  
    The power bank must be able to charge while supplying power as well - not all can do this. 
    Also note that these splitters may only provide 100 Mbit, not gigabit speeds.
2. Put a UPS on your POE switch.  This will permit all the POE devices to enjoy good power, but does NOT protect you from a cabling disconnection between switch and host.
3. There is nothing stopping you from doing both other than parts cost, and periodic battery replacements.  A proper UPS should last 5-8 years, a cheap UPS will get 2-3 years before the battery has "no capacity"   
    I presume a USB power bank will be somewhere in the middle, with an expected life of 4-5 years.